# Unpickling objects after renaming a module

Tags: python, numpy, pickle

I have a problem loading objects via `numpy.load` after renaming a module.
Here's a simple example showing the problem.

Imagine having a class defined in `mymodule.py`:

```
class MyClass(object):
    a = "ciao"
    b = [1, 2, 3]

    def __init__(self, value=2):
        self.value = value
```

from a python session I can simply create an instance and save it:

```
import numpy as np
import mymodule

instance = mymodule.MyClass()
np.save("dump.npy", instance)
```

Loading the file works nicely (even from a fresh session started in the same folder):

```
np.load("dump.npy")
```

If I now rename the module:

```
mv mymodule.py mymodule2.py
```

the loading fails. This is expected, but I was hoping that by importing the module before loading:

```
import mymodule2 as mymodule
```

the object definition could be found ... but it does not work.
This means that:
 1. I do not understand how it works
 2. I am forced to keep a symbolic link to the renamed file in a project I am partially refactoring.

Is there anything else I can do do avoid the symbolic link solution ? and to avoid having the same problem in the future ?

Thanks a lot,
marco
[this is my first question here, sorry If I am doing something wrong]

Comment: It was quite interesting to me, after renaming a file, I cannot deserialize/load the original pickled objects!

Answer (score 9):

NumPy [uses `pickle`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.11.2/numpy/lib/format.py#L592) for arrays with objects, but adds a header on top of it. Therefore, you'll need to do a bit more than coding a custom [`Unpickler`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pickle.html#pickle.Unpickler):

```
import pickle

from numpy.lib.format import read_magic, _check_version, _read_array_header


class RenamingUnpickler(pickle.Unpickler):
    def find_class(self, module, name):
        if module == 'mymodule':
            module = 'mymodule2'
        return super().find_class(module, name)


with open('dump.npy', 'rb') as fp:
    version = read_magic(fp)
    _check_version(version)
    dtype = _read_array_header(fp, version)[2]
    assert dtype.hasobject
    print(RenamingUnpickler(fp).load())
```

Comment: Thanks @wrwrwr, the `RenamingUnpickler` class works for general purpose, not only NumPy pickle. I used the class to recreate pickle objects that was referring renamed modules and  classes.

Comment: What exactely is necessary ontop of coding a custom unpickler? I have a similar problem with `keras`/`tensorflow.keras` and would need a little hint (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60193908) please).

Comment: I know this is quite an old comment, but I have just used it to fix some errors.  Can this be extended to an npz file instead of a npy file?

Comment: @dtward pose it as a new question :)