# Renaming python package with backwards compatibility (for pickle)

Tags: python, module, package, rename, pickle

I have a Python package `foo` (including GitHub repo) that I want to make public soon and also register as a pypi package. Unfortunately the name `foo` does already exist in the pypi registry, so I want to rename the package to `bar` including the repo.

However, I have created result files with the `foo` package and saved with `pickle` which were time-consuming so that I don't want to recompute them with the renamed package. Is there a way to rename the package but still be able to access the files correctly afterwards (as objects of the renamed package)?

Apart from the renamed package directory and changes in `setup.py` and some imports, the code itself will stay the same (modules, classes, functions etc.). I just want to go from

```
foo/
├── docs/
├── tests/
├── setup.py
└── foo/
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── file1.py
    └── file2.py
```

to

```
bar/
├── docs/
├── tests/
├── setup.py
└── bar/
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── file1.py
    └── file2.py
```

Is there a way to do this?

I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3):

Someone else might have a better idea, but I tried a few things and I don't think there is a a way to do exactly what you want. What you could do though is properly rename the module and then do a bit of hackery to keep using your pickled files, assuming that I've understood your situation correctly and the pickled files are work you did with the module which aren't part of the module itself, though even then the same approach should work. It is necessary that the name of your package is reasonably unique and the new name you pick is the exact same length. If so you'll be able to open a file pickled with the previous module by doing a textual replacement of the pickled data... most likely. I'd of course make a backup copy of all the pickled data before trying it but if I create a package bar containing a module test with a class A and then save a pickled copy of an instantiation of that class it can't be loaded again if I rename the package Bar. But:

```
f = open('pickletest.pk','rb')
pickle.loads(f.read().replace(b'bar',b'Bar'))
```

does work. Of course it is important that b'bar' doesn't occur anywhere in the pickled data in reference to something other than the package name which is a reasonable assumption if the actual module name you use is relatively unique. If you rename the package bar2 it doesn't work without further modifications to the pickled files. You could parse the pickle language further to ensure what you're doing doesn't cause any problems but it would be a lot of work.

Edit:

Just looked into it a bit more and if you really want to be safe you can code a custom unpickler to use with your legacy data, this would prevent issues with your module name appearing in say a textual data element or something and would allow you to rename the module as you saw fit without having to manually parse the pickled stream [see here and note that the numpy step wouldn't be relevant to you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40914066/unpickling-objects-after-renaming-a-module)